# Selecting values from multiple select option box - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select values in a multiple select option box. When i run my current code below, no item is selected in the option box but when i do parseInt(value) it only selects just the first option.

When i console.log(selected), it returns 4,5. How can insert 4,5 into $("#edit-items") to make it select both values in the option box.

PS: Sorry for my english

**JS**

```
 var selected = $(this).attr('data-items');  returns 4,5
 items = parseInt(selected)
 $("#edit-items").val([items]);
```

Comment: Can u plz show the html code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseInt()` will only parse the first integer from `4,5`. If you want to get all the intgers as an array, split the string and call `parseInt()` on each array element.

```
items = selected.split(',').map(str => parseInt(str));
$("#edit-items").val(items);
```